# How to capture response of a Bean shell sampler

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

[image]

Above is my code i have written to hit a web service whose endpoint is expecting a Byte Stream object.
I am able to do that but i am not getting any response.
I have to test the response.
Though i am getting 200 ok but a string is sent in response that i am not getting.
[image]

[image]

**And the response is blank**
[image]

How can I get the response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In order to read server's response you need to use [URLConnection.getInputStream() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8//docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream--), not OutputStream
2. In order to convert stream to string you can use [IOUtils.toString() method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))
3. In order to return data you can use [`return` keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)
4. Minimal working code is below, adjust as per your needs:

   ```
   import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
   import java.net.URL;
   import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
   import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

   URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
   HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   con.setRequestMethod("GET");
   String response = IOUtils.toString(con.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   return response;
   ```

---

- Be aware of fact that JMeter is built on top of [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) so you can use the power of these libraries in order to create HTTP requests, see [QuickStart wiki page](https://wiki.apache.org/HttpComponents/QuickStart) to get ramped up in minutes
- Be aware that starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for comprehensive explanation, benchmarks, code samples, etc.

Comment: My web service does not support get request.

Comment: Doesn't matter, just add `String response = IOUtils.toString(con.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
return response;` lines to the end of your script and you should see response data

Comment: Don't forget to add these lines to the beginning of script as well `import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;`

Comment: One more thing, Is it like speed wise Java Request > JSR223 > Beanshell...?

Comment: Java Request is the fastest, JSR223 with Groovy is second, Beanshell is the slowest: [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance)

Answer (score 2):

You can add your output by using the [SampleResult](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) object:

```
String output = "...";

SampleResult.setResponseData( output );
SampleResult.setDataType( org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.TEXT );
```

Comment: Do you want me to add this code in the BeanShell Sampler...as it is.?

Comment: It is not working. Getting an error Jmeter.exception: error invoking bsh method:...

Comment: If you create a new beanshell sampler with just my code, is it working?

Comment: it worked this way :


SampleResult.setResponseData(Respvar.toString());

Comment: I couldn't see in your question the full code. So I gave the general solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153102/discussion-between-learner-and-user7294900).